# Flink run job with remote jar file

Tags: apache-flink

I'm new to flink and trying to submit my flink program to my flink cluster.

I have a flink cluster running on remote kubernetes and a blob storage on Azure.

I know how to submit a flink job when I have the jar file on my local machine but no idea how to submit the job with the remote jar file(the jar can be access by https)

checked the documents and it seems doesn't provide something like what we do in [spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can use an init container to download the job jar into a shared volume, then submit the local jar to Flink. See this example for GCS https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flink-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/config/samples/flinkoperator_v1alpha1_remotejobjar.yaml

Comment: @Dagang Yes, I think I have to create a restful server or a copy task to shared volumne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use an init container to download the job jar into a shared volume, then submit the local jar to Flink.

Ads: Google's Flink Operator supports remote job jar, see this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flink-on-k8s-operator).